# Display dialog on client-side before form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I have a form that works on its own using required attributes in each input to make sure the user inputs a value. IE:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="formcontainer">
        <div class="formText">
            First Name <span class="required">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox" id="test">
            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div class="formText">
             Last Name <span class="required">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="formBox"><input name="lastName" type="text" required /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="formButton" id="submit">
            <asp:Button onclick="btnRequestSampleSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="formButton" id="reset">
             <input type="reset" value="Reset" tabindex="8"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

To save space, I have about 6 other fields in the form, but wanted to give you an idea. When I submit the form, the page refreshes. All fine and dandy except I wanted to add in a .dialog box on the submit button so that it lets the user know that the form went through. So I added this:

```
       $('.buttons #submit').on('click', function (e) {
            $('#dialog').dialog({                    
                 position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
           });                
            $('#fade').show();
            return false;            
        });
```

(#fade) is just an opacity box that fills the screen so when the user clicks on it, the box closes and the page will refresh. When I add in the bottom script, the validations work, but if the user hits enter or clicks on the submit button before everything is filled out, the form is submitted without having the rest of the input fields filled in. If I take out the submit JS here with the dialog, everything works fine, including validations, but I want to add the .dialog so the user knows the form is submitted properly. I can't figure out how to combine all this and make it work. Any suggestions?

Also this is done in c# so the btnRequestSampleSubmit is tying how the form is submitted to an email using the input fields.

Comment: Why do you return false?

Comment: Is the form submitted asynchronously?

Comment: no json here, just a straight submit

Comment: i forgot originally about the return false, i took that out, it doesn't fix anything

Comment: Change `return false` to `return true`

Comment: Just a usability question then: Shouldn't the user notice the submit? Why show a dialog at all and why before the submit happens?

Comment: adding return true didnt do anything just submitted the form and showed the validation error

Comment: When you talk about validators you mean the `required` attribute I assume? No other JS based validation?

Comment: correct, just the "required" attribute in the input

Comment: yes the user sees the page reload, but sometimes people might think, did it go through or did the page just  reload? you get what I'm saying?

Comment: No. :-D Pages don't just reload. You could display the dialog after the page has reloaded. That would make more sense to me. Nevermind.

Comment: well I was trying to have it work on the click is all

Comment: Oh you have a button click event. Sorry. In place of `return true` write `$('#myForm').submit();`

Comment: ... and then return false.

Comment: Just noticed this is an ASP.NET WebForms with combined jQuery. Uhuhuh.

Comment: the form submits before you get to that point, so when I take out the return false, the form is already submitted by that point, adding in $('#myForm').submit(); is just doubling the effect

Comment: yes this is jquery with webforms

Comment: I do not know much about ASP.NET. Commented cuz it was tagged with jQuery and JS. Adding event.preventDefault() would help in the onClick handler??

Comment: Due to the nature of the problem is impossible to reproduce in a fiddle... so I can only suggest to change the event you are attaching the dialog to: Instead of `#submit.click` could you have it on `#myForm.submit`? I am not sure, but somehow you have to give the browser the time to validate the form. Click happens too soon (triggers) validation - not tested - not sure either

Comment: You could put your JavaScript code in a function and add it to the onclientclick attribute of your server-side webforms control. Currently you have a div above the button, which is pretty awkward. There is an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx